# left outer join with sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am trying to select course number from courses where the students have gotten grades

first I select where the students have gotten grades for every grade_type_code

```
SELECT z.STUDENT_ID ,m.GRADE_TYPE_CODE,COUNT(*) AS COURSE_NUM
FROM STUDENT z, GRADE m,SECTION s, COURSE w
WHERE z.STUDENT_ID = m.STUDENT_ID
AND m.SECTION_ID = s.SECTION_ID
AND s.COURSE_NO = w.COURSE_NO
GROUP BY z.STUDENT_ID,m.GRADE_TYPE_CODE
```

than I try to do left outer join

```
SELECT COURSE_NO
FROM COURSE lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT z.STUDENT_ID ,m.GRADE_TYPE_CODE,COUNT(*) AS COURSE_NUM
FROM STUDENT z, GRADE m,SECTION s, COURSE w
WHERE z.STUDENT_ID = m.STUDENT_ID
AND m.SECTION_ID = s.SECTION_ID
AND s.COURSE_NO = w.COURSE_NO
GROUP BY z.STUDENT_ID,m.GRADE_TYPE_CODE) rt
ON lt.COURSE_NO = rt.COURSE_NO;
```

Comment: You're joining on `rt.COURSE_NO` but this field is not included in the select of your subquery. On the other hand, are you sure that your subquery actually returns student who've got a grade in ALL grade type?

Comment: I was calling the whole table rt, I need to have it in the select ?

Comment: yes, since rt represents your subquery, any field you need from this alias must be included in the select of the subquery

Comment: I thought I did have subquery that actually returns student who've got a grade in ALL grade type by doing count which would not give me a null result

Comment: Not sure what you mean by students who "got a grade in ALL grade type".  Is there a table that lists grade types?

Comment: doing the COUNT and grouping by student and grade type returns the number of grade for each grade type for each student. But if there are 7 grade types, the count won't help you ensuring that each student has 7 grades.

Comment: I am missing a grade column which would be something like this... select student_id, numeric_grade, grade_type_code....so I would actually need to count numeric_grade instead of grade_type_code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  c.course_no
from
  course c,
  section s,
  grade g
where
  s.course_no = c.course_no and
  g.section_id = s.section_id
group by
  c.course_no
having
  count(distinct g.grade_type_code) = 
  (select count(distinct grade_type_code) from grade);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7826/1/0

Comment: Good answer, and I'm not knocking it, but it is a shame that a google search for "left outer join with sub-query" brings one to a SO answer that contains no left outer joins.